# Values divisible by 3

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I've made a function that takes a list of integers (l) and prints all variations of these integers as below:

```
def answer(l):
    for i in range(0, len(l)+1): 
        for y in itertools.permutations(l, i): 
            s = str(y).replace(',', '')
            p =  s.replace(' ', '')
    answer([3,3,7])
```

This returns:

()
(3)
(3)
(7)
(33)
(37)
(33)
(37)
(73)
(73)
(337)
(373)
(337)
(373)
(733)

How do I now find out which of these values is divisible by 3 using x % 3 = 0?

Comment: Erm… you seem to know how to do this already (since you say in your question "using x % 3 = 0")?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't return anything; there's no **return** statement to provide a value, and your call is inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right.  You want something like

```
if y % 3 == 0:
    # whatever you want to do with those numbers.
```

If you want them in a list, you can use a comprehension:

```
tri = [x if x%3 == 0 for x in itertools.permutations(l, i)]
```

---

RESPONSE TO OP COMMENTS

"So how do I now access these string values within the p variable in order to find out whether they are divisible by 3?"

You don't: a string is not divisible by and integer.  I expect that what you want is to convert the numeric portion to an integer and test *that*.

Take the **p** value, skip the parentheses, and convert.  I'll break the code into smaller steps; you can combine it once you see the process:

```
    for y in itertools.permutations(l, i): 
        s = str(y).replace(',', '')
        p =  s.replace(' ', '')
        num_str = p[1:-1]
        if len(num_str) > 0:
            value = int(num_str)
            if value % 3 == 0:
                print value, "is divisible by 3"
            else:
                print value, "does not have trinary nature"
        else:
            print p, "empty number"
```

Output:

```
() empty number
3 is divisible by 3
3 is divisible by 3
7 does not have trinary nature
33 is divisible by 3
37 does not have trinary nature
33 is divisible by 3
37 does not have trinary nature
73 does not have trinary nature
73 does not have trinary nature
337 does not have trinary nature
373 does not have trinary nature
337 does not have trinary nature
373 does not have trinary nature
733 does not have trinary nature
733 does not have trinary nature
```

Comment: So I can't apply your if statement to 'y', because 'y' returns tuples, as below:    ()
(3,)
(4,)
(7,)
(3, 4)
(3, 7)
(4, 3)
(etc)
This is why I've removed commas and spaces after I converted them to strings. So how do I now access these string values within the p variable in order to find out whether they are divisible by 3?

Comment: Prune, you are amazing! Thank you. This is exactly what I need.